# Hide Map Layer, Keep Vector Layers Visible

Tags: javascript, openlayers

I currently have a map page displaying an ordnance survey map plus a number of vector layers for various varieties of markers etc.

The OS map is loaded as a pair of tile layers which automatically select based on minzoom/maxzoom settings. The map is displayed using the following sequence:

```
    target: 'map',
        view: new ol.View({
            projection: 'EPSG:27700',
            extent: [ -238375.0, 0.0, 900000.0, 1376256.0 ],
            resolutions: tilegrid.getResolutions(),
            minZoom: 0,
            maxZoom: 13, 
            center: [ myEast, myNorth ],
            zoom: 8
        })
    });
```

The various vector layers are individually selected using tick boxes and switched on or off by a simple handling function viz example:

```
    function handleStation(cb) {
        layerStation.setVisible( cb.checked);
    };
```

I have been trying to make the map layer similarly switchable using each of the following in turn. None work.

```
    function handleMapping(cb) {
    map.layer[0].setVisible( cb.checked);
    };

    function handleMapping(cb) {
    map.tileGrid().setVisible( cb.checked);
    };

    function handleMapping(cb) {
    map.tileGrid.setVisible( cb.checked);
    };

    function handleMapping(cb) {
    map.layer.canvas.setVisible( cb.checked);
    };

    function handleMapping(cb) {
    map.layers[0].setVisible( cb.checked);
    };

    function handleMapping(cb) {
    map.View.setVisible( cb.checked);
    };

    function handleMapping(cb) {
    map.setVisible( cb.checked);
    };
```

Is there a simple setting I should be using but have missed to enable the map layer to be hidden whilst keeping the vector layers visible?

Thanks.

Comment: To change the visiblity of the base layer use `map,getLayers().getArray()[0].setVisible(cb.checked)`

Comment: Mike - thank you for the prompt response. Works perfectly with the comma after map replaced by a full stop.